# Detecting window close before load completion

Tags: javascript

I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) and it is working fine

```js
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

But if the document load is not yet completed, this one is not working.
Is there a way to detect browser closing before page full loading, i.e. before `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: you can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3888902/12348877